# change github repo ownership

Tags: github

I have a repo that is owned by me. Now I want to move it to an organization what is the best way of doing this? just change ownership? I am just slightly worried of messing up permissions and I have never done this before.

I want to be able to do is change the ownership from ME -> NEWOWNER. (I set up a new account let's say newowner@example.com) I have added myself as an owner of the organization under NEWOWNER, let's call it newOwnerOrg. Can I just move the owenership to newOwnerOrg, then fork the repo from newOwnerOrg and start to work on it like before, creating pull requests, etc?

Like I said this is my first time doing this and pretty worried. I have read [this gist](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/8972566) is this still the best way to do it? or is there another article that I have missed? Thanks guys :)